# Using stream response in Laravel on big requests (hundreds of MB)

Tags: laravel

I have a React application that fetches store from Laravel backend. This store contains base64 images (thumbnails), meaning it can be really large. Naturally, these images are then cached in Local Storage.

Files are stored in DigitalOcean Spaces and are encrypted with Laravel function `encrypt()`. This is important because these images are critical from business perspective. Frontend injects base64 encoded images right into src attribute.

I use Laravel Storage facade to fetch these thumbnails from DigitalOcean Spaces.

Cached files are fetched locally from Local Storage.

From server comes single JSON response which looks like:

```
{
  "user": ...,
  "photos": [
    {
       "id": 1,
       "thumbnail": "base64...."
       ...
    }
  ... more data
  ]
}
```

This response is built by multiple serialization functions that converts Eloquent models into JSON, filters some information and then all parts are joined together in this JSON representation of Redux Store.

But I'm afraid of exceeding the memory limit, so I think about using stream response. Is it a good solution?

I found only info about streaming downloads, couldn't find information about using streams for these kinds of requests.

Thank you very much for the reply

Comment: Where are these base64 images stored?

Comment: @apokryfos Meaning on backend? They are stored in DigitalOcean Spaces, but it needs to go through backend as files are encrypted - these images are critical from business perspective.

Comment: You will need to provide more information. For example can you use Guzzle to open a stream to those files? Do you need to also base64_decode them?

Comment: I added more information, so hopefully it will help.

Comment: Running out of memory while building the JSON response is probably a valid concern but I don't think streaming the whole JSON help you in this particular case. I suggest building an endpoint which has the sole purpose of streaming an image, and then load images using `<img src="/your-laravel-streaming-enpoint/1/thumbnail.png" />`. This enndpoint can be responsible for ensuring only authorised users can see the images